# I have an array full of objects. All objects have key author and publisher. I want to take out the publisher who publish most different authors

Tags: javascript

Here I am setting the empty object with key (publisher) and value
author;

Also I tried and I push them in the empty array

```
let publisherAutors = {};
let pushedAutorsPerPublisher = [];
```

With this for loop i`m taking the elements from my library , which are books(objects), and i take out the publishers and the autors

```
for (let i = 0; i < library.length; i++) {
  const element = library[i];
  autorCount = 0;
```

I think my problem is here , with the if statements, i wanna compare but something is going wrong

```
  if (
    element.publisher === element.publisher &&
    element.autor === element.autor
  ) {
    console.log(`Yes`);
```

Here i push to the empty array

```
    pushedAutorsPerPublisher.push(element.publisher, element.autor);
    console.log(element.publisher, element.autor);
  }
```

Here I`m adding key/ value to the empty object, but Its not helping me , because they goes only once in the empty object

```
  publisherAutors[element.publisher] = element.autor;
}

console.log(publisherAutors);
console.log(pushedAutorsPerPublisher);
```

My main problem is to make object , or array that holds them and
count how many different authors have each publisher .

Comment: Run through your array, and build a separate object that uses publishers as keys, with "how many authors" as value, and just count everything up. Then "finding the publisher with the most/fewest authors" becomes a matter of analyzing _that_ object instead of your original array. Or, of course, generate your array with the author count already in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the ideas Mike !, I`m very fresh with the programming and next time I will follow your advice Barmar .

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to store every publisher's published authors into their respective arrays, and then use `filter` and `indexOf` to filter out the duplicates. Then, return the largest array.

[Here is a link to how you would use `filter` and `indexOf` to filter duplicates.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: No worries, do you mind accepting my answer as correct if it ends up working out? Good luck with your project! :)